# Two simple CSS problems

Tags: css

I have two simple problems I couldn't fix:

1. When over "Home" you can see the borders are no longer in radius.
   What can I do to fix it?
2. When over "Services" There's this gray line
   on the top-right of the popup menu. I want to discard it.

   ```
       <nav>
       <ul>
           <li><a id="homefix" href="#">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
           <li><a id="serv" href="#">SERVICES</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
                   <li><a id="ecomfix" href="#">e-Commerce</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>
           <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
           <form>
           <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
           <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search" /> 
           </form>
       </ul>
   </nav>
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuvalsab/M9D89/

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: +1 for showing a jsfiddle as a first time user. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nav ul li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M9D89/6/

Answer (score 0):

Applying a full `border radius` seems to work. It doesn't look bad, and the border radius doesn't seem to be applied in #homefix. Why can't you just do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/M9D89/3/